# The purpose of using Q-Learning algorithm

Tags: theory, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

What is the point of using Q-Learning? I have used an example code that represents 2D board with pawn moving on this board. At the right end of the board there is goal which we want to reach. After completion of algorithm I have a q table with values assigned to every state-action junction. Is it all about getting this q table to see which state-actions (which actions are the best in case of specific states) pairs are the most useful? That's how I understand it right now. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it all about getting this q table to see which state-actions (which
>   actions are the best in case of specific states) pairs are the most
>   useful?

Yep! That's pretty much it. Given a finite state space, Q-learning is guaranteed to eventually learn the optimal policy. Once an optimal policy is reached (also known as convergence) every time the agent is in a given state *s*, it looks in its Q-table for the action *a* with the highest reward for that *(s, a)* pair.